# Length of countably many intervals (2)

Tags: real-analysis

I already posted this question along with a related one but only the other one got answered, so I'm reposting this.

---

The following is a proof from my textbook. I have 2 questions, which are in bold.

**Theorem:** Let $(I_n)$ and $(J_k)$ be sequences of intervals such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$. If the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)\le\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$. Thus, if the $J_k$ are also pairwise disjoint, then the two sums are equal.

**Proof:**

Suppose, to the contrary, that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$.

Then, for some $N$, we must have $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ell(J_k)$ .

Of course, we also have $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$ .

But now, by expanding each $J_k$ slightly and shrinking each $I_n$ slightly, we may suppose that the $J_k$ are open and the $I_n$ are closed.

Thus, the $J_k$ form an open cover for the compact set $\bigcup_{n=1}^N I_n$.

And here is the contradiction: Since we have $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>\sum_{k=1}^M\ell(J_k)$, for any $M$, the sets ($J_k$) form an open cover for  that admits no finite subcover. **Could you please explain this? Also, where do we use the fact that the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint?**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $J_k=[a_k, b_k]$(it could also be $J_k=[a_k, b_k)$ or $J_k=(a_k, b_k]$, it doesn't matter, you'll see) we get that $J_k \subset (a_k-\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}, b_k+\frac{\epsilon}{2^k})$ and note that the sum of these extensions increases the sum of the lengths of $J_k$ by $\epsilon$ which can be made arbitrarilty small.

This is how we show that $J_k$ is contained in an open set. We do a similar thing for the $I_n$ but by making them smaller and thus closed. The reason we do this is because then the union of finitely many $I_n$ will also be closed and (assuming they are also bounded, which you didn't say btw) their union will be ***compact*** and therefore they will have to be covered by finitely many of the open $J_k$.

You use the fact that the $I_n$ are disjoint when you write $l(I_1 \cup ... \cup I_n) = l(I_1)+...+l(I_n) $